# How to listen for changes in numerous sub-collections in Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am building admin part of my app and as part of the functionality I added a chat section, where the admin or user can chat with each other. I am storing the conversations in sub collection in every user collection, so it is convenient to access them, but now I need to alert the admin when any of the users message him, so this turns out to be a little tricky. For now I am getting every user message feed like this:

```
return this.afs.collection('users').doc(id).collection('messages').valueChanges();
```

But how to listen for value changes on all users 'messages' subcollections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely certain, but I think your looking for [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query). Such a query allows you to select documents from all `messages` collections, no matter what `user` document they're under.

Comment: That's it! And the neat part is that it works with Angularfire! Thanks man, I will try it right away!